# Access violation between lines

Tags: delphi, stack, delphi-5

The following code seems to work okay on my machine, but gives an access violation for a customer.

```
procedure TSummaryThread.Execute;
var
  When: String;
begin
  try
    FCarcassListCS := TCriticalSection.Create;
    FCarcassLists := TObjectList.Create;
    while (not Terminated) do
      begin
        try
          When := 'GetMessage';
          if (GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0))
            then begin
                  if (Msg.message = WM_SUMMARISE)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_SUMMARISE';
                        Update(True);
                       end
                else if (Msg.message = WM_UPDATE)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_UPDATE';
                        Update(False);
                       end
                else if (Msg.message = WM_RELOAD_SETUP)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_RELOAD_SETUP';
                        ReloadSetup(Pointer(Msg.wParam));
                       end
                else if (Msg.message = WM_SEND_TO)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_SEND_TO';
                        SendToThread(Pointer(Msg.wParam));
                       end
                else if (Msg.message = WM_UPDATE_ORDER_SUM)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_UPDATE_ORDER_SUM';
                        DoOrderSummary;
                       end
                else if (Msg.message = WM_SUMMARISE_LOAD)
                  then begin
                        When := 'WM_SUMMARISE_LOAD';
                        LoadAndSummarise;
                       end
                  else begin
                        When := 'DispatchMessage';
                        DispatchMessage(Msg);
                       end;
                 end;
        except
          on E: Exception do
            Log('Exception (' + E.ClassName + ') in summary  thread at ' + When + ': ' + E.Message);
        end;
      end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Log('Exception (' + E.ClassName + ') in summary  thread (2) at ' + When + ': ' + E.Message);
end;

procedure TSummaryThread.Update(Full: Boolean);
var
  CarcassList: TObjectList;
  Where: String;
begin
  try
    Where := 'GetList';
    FCarcassListCS.Enter;
    try
      if (FCarcassLists.Count = 0)
        then raise Exception.Create('No carcass list found');
      CarcassList := FCarcassLists[0] as TObjectList;
      FCarcassLists.Extract(CarcassList);
    finally
      FCarcassListCS.Leave;
    end;
    FSummaryListCS.Enter;
    try
      Where := 'LoadFiles';
      SetFiles;
      try
        Where := 'AddCcs';
        CarcassList := GetShiftCarcassList(CarcassList);
        AddCarcassesToSummaries(CarcassList, Full);
      finally
        CloseFiles;
      end;
      Where := 'Send';
      SendSummaries;
      Where := 'Done';
    finally
      FreeAndNil(CarcassList);
      FSummaryListCS.Leave;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      E.Message := 'Update(' + Where + '): ' + E.Message;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

From the logging I can tell that `When := 'WM_UPDATE';` is being hit and `Where := 'GetList';` is not. This leads me to think that the access violation is occurring when the local `Where` variable in the `Update()` procedure is being added to the Stack.

What extra diagnostics could I add to help work out what's causing the issue? Is there any way I can check if the stack is corrupted and/or where the `Where` variable is being added to the stack?

I realize this is a rather vague question, but I cannot think of anything to try and narrow this down.

Exact error is:

> Exception (EAccessViolation) in summary thread at WM_UPDATE: Access violation at address 004B6759 in module 'Application.exe'. Read of address 00000008

Comment: (1) exact error message? (2) are you sure the thread object is valid and not already gone?

Comment: How do you know an Access Violation is occurring? What is the actual symptom/log? Failure to put a variable on the stack does not generate an AV, and assigning a value (especially a literal) to a `String` does not put that data on the stack anyway. There is nothing in this code that would cause an AV where you claim, unless the AV is coming from the RTL's Memory Manager itself, in which case your app is screwed and you need to restart it.

Comment: And BTW, when it comes to tracking down memory problems, try to reduce memory allocations, don't use allocations to track the problem. Use [`OutputDebugString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) for logging, and use a tool like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to see those messages when you are running the app outside of the IDE debugger.

Comment: @JensG I have added the exact error message. The top piece of code is from the TSummaryThread.Execute method so I think the thread object is still valid.

Comment: The error message you showed means a member of a class is being accessed via a `nil` pointer. The only place that the code you showed is accessing any such pointer is when calling `Update()` via the `Self` pointer, which in of itself will not raise an AV until `Update()` tries to access a member of the calss, or if `Update()` itself is virtual and thus relies on the called object's vtable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Update() is not virtual. Declared like so **procedure Update(Full: Boolean);**

Comment: @Energ1ser: A non-virtual procedure call is just a simple jump, so the vtable is not involved. The code you showed cannot raise an AV, so it has to be in code you did not show.

Comment: Your code is not reaching the line that prepends `'Update('+Where+')'` to `E.Message`, so the AV cannot be occurring inside the `try` block you have shown for `Update()`, it has to be happening elsewhere. Unless the prepend itself is crashing, which goes back to the possibility of the RTL Memory Manager being corrupted. If that were happening, you could be corrupting random memory at any time from any code location, and `Update()` would just be an unsuspecting victim if it happened to access corrupted memory. That is a much rarer possibility, and much harder to diagnose and fix if it is random

Comment: What context is the try...except block running in? It appears to be a global name space, yet you've got an object 'Msg' that it's referring to. This could possibly be the source of the exception. I'd imagine it should be located within a TSummaryThread class member that has a 'message' tag at the end of it. Please show the method declaration that contains it in the class header along with how it appears around the try...except block, and where the 'Msg' object instance or reference is declared.

Comment: I never thought of the prepend crashing. I still think it has to be in the code provided as there is nothing between the `When := 'WM_UPDATE';` line and the `Update(False)'` line. There is also nothing after it but the `try` block.

Comment: What is "Msg" defined as?

Comment: @davea Msg is the Windows.TMsg record

Comment: @Energ1ser: Actually, there is code executed before the `try` inide of `Update()` - the prologs the set up the stack frame and the exception handler frame. Neither of which can throw an AV. And you did not answer David's question about where the `TMsg` is actually coming from. Is it a `WindowProc`? An `OnMessage` event handler? A `message` handler? You need to provide more context info if you expect people to help any further.  As it stands, the code you showed is NOT diagnosable as-is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added more code, but cannot add anymore without having to add hundreds of lines.

Comment: Put madexcept in the process and get some real info. Looks like a nil object. Perhaps self is nil.

Comment: It seems to me that `self` is the ONLY candidate.

Comment: +1 to `Self`. That's why I asked question (2) above.

Comment: @Energ1ser said: "_but cannot add anymore without having to add hundreds of lines_". The full class definition could prove helpful and shouldn't be too much to add.

Comment: @Energ1ser said: "_The top piece of code is from the TSummaryThread.Execute method so I think the thread object is still valid_". Your logic is flawed. The top piece of code is outside the **while** loop. So the instance could initially be valid. Then another thread destroys it, and the next iteration fails. I suggest you add debug logging to know when your summary thread is destroyed.

Comment: Finally, I'm a little concerned at how you've added code to your question in a 'piece-meal' fashion. Are you sure it's ***100%*** identical? E.g. If there's other code missing, perhaps `When` simply holds a value from the previous iteration and is not accurately reflecting _when_ the error occurrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your executable's Project Options, locate the Linker settings. Ensure that the `Map file` setting is configured to `Detailed`. While you're on the Linker settings page, check the `Image base` address. It is most likely $00400000, if not write it remember what it is set to.

Rebuild your executable (I'm assuming your project is a single executable, which it appears to be based on the exception text you provided). In the compiler's output directory, you should find a file named "Application.map". Open this file in your favorite text editor.

Now, take the address reported in the exception message (in this case $004B6759). Subtract the executable's base address ($00400000) from the exception's address. This gives you $B6759. Subtract $1000 (I'm pretty sure it's subtract, if not someone will point out that it should add in the comments). Leaving $B5759. This is the offset within the executable where the access violation occurred.

Using the map file that you loaded earlier, look in the `Detailed map of segments` section. Locate the first entry that is less than or equal to $B5759 and is immediately followed by a segment that is greater than $B5759. Scan unit name of associated with the segment (it's the one marked with "M=").

Search for the unit name in the map file, you will find a section titled "Line numbers for XXX(..) segment .text" where XXX is the name of the unit you are looking for. In this section will be a list of line numbers and the offset to the first byte of code for that line number. Locate the first line number (based on the address) that is less than or equal to $B5759 and is immediately followed by an offset greater than $B5759.

This will tell you the line number (and source file) that contains the compiled code that is actually causing the access violation.

And as others have stated, given that the exception is a read of $8, you are likely trying to read from a nil pointer or object.. probably the second field of record or object (assuming 32bit code).

Best of luck.